# the lives of children or the children's lives?

Tags: word-choice

Is ***the children's lives*** grammatically wrong? I am not a native English speaker. It just sounds more nature for me to say ***the lives of children*** instead of ***the children's lives***.  Or these two are both correct? Thank you !

Comment: We need more context. *The lives of  children* is generic, talking about this in the abstract. *The children's lives* refers to specific children; which children should be clear from context.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't grammatically wrong. However, the equivalent to **the lives of children** (meaning children in general) would be **children's lives**. **The children's lives** implies that you are referring to a particular group of children.

'The aim of the organisation is to improve children's lives.'

''The parents were drowned but the children's lives were saved.'

Answer (score -2):

We use *of* with nonliving things, for example we do not write "the table's wood" we prefer to write "the wood of the table" and "the leg of the chair"

In this question "children's lives" is correct because children are living things

Comment: Who’s ***we*** in this scenario?

Comment: i  am generally referring it